# How to remove blank inverted comma from my list and tuple in python?

Tags: python

I am a new python developer. I will be glad if you help me with this. The problem is I made a list and tuple. A user has to type some comma-separated numbers.
So I was expecting this result :

```
List :  ['3', '4', '2', '3', '5']
Tuple : ('3', '4', '2', '3', '5')
```

and also the number should show in ascending order. It worked by the below code but shows some extra inverted comma so How to remove those blank commas.

Type some comma-separated numbers: 4 4 5 6 2 3 1

```
List  :  [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5', '6']      
Tuple :  [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5', '6']
```

This is the code I am using to make the list and tuple in ascending order. Another thing is when I give the int() method in the input so that the user only can type the number, not any string. It shows an error so how to do that?

```
values = input("Type some comma separated numbers: ")
list = values.split()
tuple = tuple(list)
tuple= sorted(values, reverse = False)
list= sorted(values, reverse = False)
print('List  : ', list)
print('Tuple : ', tuple)
```

Comment: Don't use `list`, `tuple` and any other builtin as variable name. This doesn't solve the problem but after `list =` you can't use: list(...).

Comment: will that solve the problem?

Comment: Why input is '4 4 5 6 2 3 1' and not '4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 1'

Comment: In your case, values.split() needs a separator argument of comma

Comment: @AshrafulIslamJoy its good practise to not keep the variables on builtin because it overwrites them

Comment: @Corralien I have just tried it only that's all. The ascending code works perfectly. The main problem is the blank inverted comma...Corralien 

Comment: @AndyKnight that's add more comma that's why I remove it. ex:Type some comma separated numbers:5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1
List  :  [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '1', '4', '5', '6', 
'7', '8']
Tuple :  [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '1', '4', '5', '6', 
'7', '8']

Comment: @Good Thanks for the advice next time I won't. ❤❤❤

Comment: The important qustion here is: _what exactly do you input_? input() is just a string - if you input `"3 , 4, 65, 45,7, 99,3 , 12,2"`  you have a string with spaces, numbers, commas. If you split by `.split()` you split by spaces so you get `["3", ",", "4," , "65," ...]` - use `print()` to debug your  code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't user `list`, `tuple`, `set` or any [reserved keywords](https://realpython.com/lessons/reserved-keywords/) as variable names.
2. Use `values.split(',')` instead of `values.split()`, you must pass the separator that will be used for splitting your string.
3. For sorting a list `sorted(<your_list>)` or `<your_list>.sort()` can be used - If you are curious to know the difference between these [two](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/what-is-the-difference-between-sort-and-sorted/349679/4)

Finally your code can be minimized to,

```
values         = input("Type some comma separated numbers: ")
list_variable  = sorted(values.split(','))
tuple_variable = tuple(list_variable)
print('List  : ', list_variable)
print('Tuple : ', tuple_variable)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer and explanation. ❤❤❤

Answer (score 1):

You can't use int() when calling input() because by separating the numbers with a space, you're creating a string with numbers that do not resemble to a base10 number, hence the ValueError you get.

For example:

```
values = '4 4 5 6 2 3 1'
int(values)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 4 5 6 2 3 1'
```

However:

```
values = '4456231'
int(values)
4456231
```

As mentioned by @Corralien, you can't use built-in reserved keywords like list and tuple (unless you delete their namespace first, but that would make things unnecessarily complex). It's also considered good syntax to don't separate the = sign for keywords with spaces. To get what you need, you could do:

```
values = input("Type some comma separated numbers: ")
l = sorted(values.split(), reverse=False)
t = sorted(tuple(l), reverse=False)
print('List  : ', l)
print('Tuple : ', t)
```

But that wouldn't get you the values as integers, in which case the best would be doing list comprehension. We use it to iterate between the values of the list l, and convert them to int in the list n.

```
values = input("Type some comma separated numbers: ")
l = sorted(values.split(), reverse=False)
n = [int(x) for x in l]
t = sorted(tuple(n), reverse=False)
print('List  : ', n)
print('Tuple : ', t)
```

However, you're asking the user to enter values that are comma separated, not spaces. Therefore, most users would enter `4,4,5,6,2,3,1` rather `4 4 5 6 2 3 1`. In that case, you'd need to adapt your code to look more like this:

```
values = input("Type some comma separated numbers: ")
l = sorted(values.split(','), reverse=False)
n = [int(x) for x in l]
t = sorted(tuple(n), reverse=False)
print('List  : ', n)
print('Tuple : ', t)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply do this:**

```
values = input("Type some comma separated numbers: ")
List=sorted(values.split(','))
Tuple=tuple(List)
print('List  : ', List)
print('Tuple : ', Tuple)
```

Comment: But I want the user to only types int numbers and the number should show in ascending order. the code you give I have done it earlier. the problem is when I give sorted() method for the ascending order consoles shows some extra blank inverted comma. So my purpose is how to remove or not show the blank inverted commas. Thank You.

Comment: This code doesn't produce any extra spaces. `List=sorted(values.split(','))`
You missed `","` in your code due to which split command took `,` too as a data.

Comment: @Bidhav .Thank You very much for your help...Nice to talk you 

Comment: @Bibhav Although your code is technically correct, PEP 8 states variable names should all be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You messed your variable names up: your code stores the `input()` into `values`.

Then you split `values` and store the splitted data it into `list` (do not use built in names as variables!).

Then you do `tuple= sorted(values, reverse = False)` which uses **the unsplit (!)** original string - not the splitted data you just created.

**THAT is your mistake you need to fix.**

Essentially you sort the *unsplit* string wich gives you a sorted list of characters of your inputs!

After that commit to one type of splitting - by spaces, by commas or whatever and stick to it.